# Robocopy - Exclude specific file from purge within subdirectory

Tags: robocopy

I want to exclude a specific file from being deleted while still performing a purge. The specific file is located within a subdirectory that does not exist in source.

Source:

```
folder1\
    file1.txt
```

Destination:

```
folder1\
    file1.txt
    folder2\
        dontdelete.txt
        delete.txt
```

If I use:

```
Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /e /purge /xf dontdelete.txt
```

Then Robocopy will delete folder2\ which contains that file, so in essence still deleting the dontdelete.txt file.

```
Source : C:\Source\
Dest : C:\Destination\
Files : *.*     
Exc Files : dontdelete.txt      
Options : *.* /V /L /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:1000000 /W:30 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   0    C:\Source\
                   1    C:\Source\folder1\
*EXTRA Dir        -1    C:\Destination\folder1\folder2\
  *EXTRA File              0    delete.txt
  *EXTRA File              0    dontdelete.txt
          same             0    file1.txt
```

If I use:

```
Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /e /purge /xd folder2 /xf dontdelete.txt
```

Then Robocopy will not look inside folder2 at all for files that should be purged.

```
Source : C:\Source\
Dest : C:\Destination\
Files : *.*     
Exc Files : dontdelete.txt      
Exc Dirs : folder2      
Options : *.* /V /L /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:1000000 /W:30 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   0    C:\Source\
                   1    C:\Source\folder1\
  *named dir      -1    C:\Destination\folder1\folder2\
          same             0    file1.txt
```

I have also tried using the entire path including the file with no difference in output.

Answer (score 1):

Mention the full destination file's path to exclude it from purge. So, instead of

> Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /e /purge /xf dontdelete.txt

use:

`Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /e /purge /xf C:\Destination\folder1\folder2\dontdelete.txt`

This works with both `/purge` and `/mir`. So `/e /purge` can be replaced with `/mir` in the command, as they are essentially the same. So the command can be:

`Robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /mir /xf C:\Destination\folder1\folder2\dontdelete.txt`

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522211).